# Calling web api from ajax

Tags: .net, ajax, web-services, api, post

I have the following code in .NET:

```
// GET api/EmailValidationStaging/5
public EmailValidation GetEmailValidation(long id)
```

This is a GET method, I am able to call it like this:

```
$("#buttonFIND").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("[removed for privacy]/webservice/api/emailvalidationstaging/" + $("#textRecordId").val() + "?key=key", function (json) {
                $("#RecordId").val(json.RecordId);
                $("#Email").val(json.Email);
                $("#Validated").val(json.Validated);
                $("#IsEmailCurrent").val(json.IsEmailCurrent);
                $("#SentOut").val(json.SentOut);
                $("#TableRecordId").addClass("showStuff");
                //alert("success");
            })
                .fail(function () { });
        });
```

Everything works perfectly!

Now I need to do the same thing but this time it is a POST method and I have no idea how to do that. Everything I tried fails, please can someone give me a decent answer. I need to call this method:

This is a POST method, I am calling:

```
// POST api/EmailValidationStaging
public HttpResponseMessage PostEmailValidation(EmailValidation emailvalidation)
```

Additional information:

I am using Fiddler Web Debugger (Fiddler2)

Under compose I have Parsed (Selected POST) and then url like this:
    [removed for privacy]/webservice/api/emailvalidationstaging/?key=key

I am using HTTP/1.1
With the following parameters:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: text/xml
```

RequestBody:
    {"MemberSSN":"999999999"}

The result I get is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Gateway Connection Failed
Date: Thu, 21 Aug 2014 18:52:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 11:52:32.933
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery post method to call the api method:

> $.post()

Here is a link for its documentation 
[jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
and make sure that your api action is marked as HttpPost

Comment: Oh wow man are you serious. I am not trying to be rude but you think I was not there??? I tried that, I tried fiddle manually building a post through that it does not work!

Comment: Can you please post what have you did as post and what problems you faced with it so we can help you.